# Call a compnent from a service

Tags: angular, observable

I have 2 component that need to communicate, and a service in the middle.

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {

  // Observable string sources
  private onOpen = new Subject<any>();

  // Observable string streams
  onOpen = this.onOpen.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  callComponentMethod() {
    this.onOpen.next();
  }

}
```

Component A

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicationService } from './communication.service.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp1',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="callMethod()">Call method from Component1</button>
  `
})
export class Component1 {

  constructor( private communicationService: CommunicationService  ) { }

  callMethod = function () {
    this.communicationService.onOpen();
  }

}
```

Component B

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicationService } from './communication.service.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp2',
  template: ``
})
export class Component2 {

  constructor( private communicationService: CommunicationService  ) {

    this.communicationService.onOpen.subscribe(
        () => {
          alert('(Component2) onOpen');
        }
      );

  }

}
```

following this plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/SmntWy0GTNdvGB5Jb3hO?p=preview the method are called but, I would like to pass a parameter. how do I do this ?

Comment: May be you can pass parameter in stream   : callComponentMethod(params) {
    this.onOpen.next(params);
  }

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: Which param you want to pass?

Comment: depends of where, right now I wish a custom typed object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few things incorrect with your implementation. Here is a working example of what you want to achieve:

[Example](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u36nnh)

You don't need to use `Subject`, you can just use a normal observable and then "push" new values to the emitter for that observable:

```
export class CommunicationService {
  // Observable string sources
  private emitter: any;
  public messageInbox: Observable<any>

  constructor(){
     this.messageInbox = Observable.create(e => this.emitter = e);
  }

  // Service message commands
  public SendMessage() {
    this.emitter.next("hello");
  }
```

The code in your components was mostly ok.

Comment: Sorry again, I am using this has kind of event, but, wouldn't EventEmitter be better ? Component A and C are not related. Also, I do not see why I need emitter and message, couldn't this be done with only 1 element ?

Comment: @Bobby Technically yes it could be a single var, however I personally think that this is a better implementation because in this case, I made the `emitter` private and the `messageInbox` public. So nothing outside this service can emit events - so separation of concerns. I'm sure `EventEmitter` would also work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Call `callComponentMethod` function of `CommunicationService`  class rather than calling `onOpen`. Second, if you want to pass the information you can do it through passing the value to `callComponentMethod` function.

Below is the modified code

### CommunicationService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {

  // Observable string sources
  private onOpen = new Subject<any>();

  // Observable string streams
  onOpen = this.onOpen.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  callComponentMethod(info:any) {
    this.onOpen.next(info);    //<-- pass the value to subscribers
  }

}
```

### Component1

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicationService } from './communication.service.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp1',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="callMethod()">Call method from Component1</button>
  `
})
export class Component1 {

  constructor( private communicationService: CommunicationService  ) { }

  callMethod = function () {
    let obj = { name : "john" }; //<-- you can pass the value from callMethod
    this.communicationService.callComponentMethod(obj);   //<-- changed here
  }

}
```